# Flabby sheaf comonad

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory, monads, sheaf-cohomology

If one Googles sufficiently hard one finds the statement that Roger Godement gives the first example of a comonad, used to compute flabby resolutions of sheaves, in his monograph "Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux". For example, see [here](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9781107340985&cid=CBO9781107340985A047&tabName=Chapter). I am interested in comonads in the category $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$, so I looked out this paper and attempted some translation. I think that the relevant part is, given a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, we define a new sheaf $C \mathscr{F}$ where
$$
C\mathscr{F}(U) = \{ \text{functions } s \colon U \longrightarrow \mathscr{E}_\mathscr{F} \mid s(x) \in \mathscr{F}_x \forall x \in U  \}
$$
where $\mathscr{E}_\mathscr{F}$ is the étalé space of $\mathscr{F}$, and $\mathscr{F}_x$ is the stalk of $\mathscr{F} $ at $x \in X$.

My question is, is this really a comonad? I have found it hard to define a natural transformation $\varepsilon \colon C \longrightarrow 1$ that would turn $C$ into a comonad. Is there another functor $\mathsf{Sh}(X) \longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(X)$ which is the comonad which is being referred to? Is the original statement incorrect?

Comment: $F_x$ is the stalk, not the skyscraper sheaf. Are you sure that you have given the correct definition of $CF$? There is no free access to the pdf you have linked.

Comment: Since the canonical map $X^\mathrm{disc} \to X$ is continuous, we get a geometric morphism $\mathbf{Set}^X \to \mathbf{Sh}(X)$, and the adjunction induces a _monad_ on $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$. _This_ is the Godement standard resolution. Notably it's not a comonad – comonads are for building projective resolutions!

Comment: Martin, apologies I meant to write stalk, I posted the question late. Also the statement I was referring to was in the preview at the bottom of the page, not in the actual pdf.

Comment: Zhen Lin, thanks for confirming my suspicions. Do you know of any comonads in $ \mathsf {Sh} (X) $?

Comment: There are plenty. Take, for instance, a continuous map $X \to Y$; then we get a geometric morphism $\mathbf{Sh}(X) \to \mathbf{Sh}(Y)$, inducing a comonad on $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$.

Comment: I should have done that topos theory course! That's something to think about.

I've also realised that the functor $C$ defined above is isomorphic to the one Weibl defines in 8.6.15 of 'An Introduction to Homological Algebra', that is the functor $$T(\mathscr{F}) = \prod_{x \in X} x_*(\mathscr{F}_x) $$ which I knew was a monad. I should have realised there was nothing new going on with $C$.